# Grunt compass:dist task failing due to Invalid CSS in bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass, bootstrap-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

**grunt build** is failing by yielding following error:

> error app/styles/directive.scss (Line 369 of
> bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss:
> Invalid CSS after "...     floor(math": expected ")", was
> ".div($grid-gutt...")

**Gruntfile.js** has `compass` and `build` task like below:

```
grunt.initConfig({

        ....
        
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: './bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false,
                raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    sourcemap: true
                }
            }
        },
        
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass:server'
            ],
            test: [
                'compass'
            ],
            dist: [
                'compass:dist',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },
        ....
    });

grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'concurrent:dist',
    ]);
```

**package.json** includes:

```
"grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.0",
```

**bower.json** includes:

```
"bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
```

Other information:

> OS: Linux Ubuntu 18.10
>
> Node: v8.17.0
>
> NPM: v6.13.4
>
> Ruby: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
>
> Compass: Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)